# Ionic/stencil Service Workers don't auto update

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, stenciljs

I'm using a ionic starter pwa and I've added service worker in my stencil.config.ts.
I've added my pwa to my mobile homepage but If I build another version of the pwa, with npm run build and then deploy the pwa, the app on my phone don't update.

Stencil doc [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/service-workers) says this but don't work for me.

```
"Also, because the files Stencil generates are hashed, every time you do a production build and push an update to your app, the service worker will know to update, therefore ensuring your users are never stuck on a stale version of your site."
```

This is my **stencil.config.ts**.

```
...
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: "www",
      serviceWorker: {
        globPatterns: [
          '**/*.{js,css,json,html,ico,png}'
        ]
      },
      ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your service worker is stuck in the `waiting` state. You'll need to create a [custom service worker](https://stenciljs.com/docs/service-workers#using-a-custom-service-worker) and then you can [trigger "skipWaiting" and reload the page](https://stenciljs.com/docs/service-workers#showing-a-reload-toast-when-an-update-is-available).

File: `src/sw.js`

```js
importScripts("workbox-v4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

self.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
  if (data === "skipWaiting") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  clients.claim();
});

self.workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);
```

File: `src/components/app-root.tsx`

```js
import { Component, h, Host, Listen } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'app-root'
})
export class AppRoot {

  @Listen("swUpdate", { target: 'window' })
  async onSWUpdate() {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();

    if (!registration || !registration.waiting) {
      // If there is no registration, this is the first service
      // worker to be installed. registration.waiting is the one
      // waiting to be activated.
      return;
    }

    registration.waiting.postMessage("skipWaiting");
    window.location.reload();
  }

  render() {
    return <Host></Host>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try asap and I'll update you about this :)

Comment: Sounds good. If you run into any issues - double check the directory in `importScripts("workbox-v4.3.1/workbox-sw.js")` matches the workbox version you have installed. The stencil docs reference `3.4.1` but the latest stencil actually installs workbox `4.3.1`.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in stencil.config.ts

```
outputTargets: [{
    type: 'www',
    serviceWorker: {
      globPatterns: [
        '**/*.{js,css,json,html,ico,png}'
      ]
    }
  }],
```

create new .htaccess with below code

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```